# Connection between generalized eigenvectors and Jordan normal form

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I have the matrix A = $ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & 3 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and want to find a matrix S such that $SAS^{-1}$ is an upper triangular matrix.

I already found that $ x = 2 $ is the eigenvalue with multiplicity 3. Then I tried finding the (generalized) eigenvectors. I got:

$ (A-2E_{3})v_{1}=0   \rightarrow  v_{1}= [1,-1,1]^{T} $

$(A-2E_{3})v_{2}=v_{1}   \rightarrow  v_{2}= [1,0,0]^{T} $

$(A-2E_{3})v_{3}=v_{2}   \rightarrow  v_{3}= [-2,1,0]^{T} $

Now I thought I just set $ S= [v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}]$, use this to find $S^{-1}$ and solve the equation $SAS^{-1}$.
But in this case I don't get an upper triangular matrix/ Jordan normal form as a result. Is my whole approach wrong?

I'm just starting off with the topic JCF and I'm having my problems with that, as you can see. So I would be very grateful for any help! Thanks in advance

Comment: For column  eigenvectors, when you make the matrix $S$  with those (gen) eigenvectors, it is then $  J =S^{-1}  A S$   that is in Jordan form. The way you wrote it is the other direction, $A = SJ S^{-1}$